# Typescript, declare a variable type must be key of an object

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have an object like the following:

```
let obj = {
  method1: () => { return "method1 called" },
  method2: () => { return "method2 called" },
  method3: () => { return "method3 called" },
}
```

I want to declare a variable, which value can only be one of the keys present in `obj`.
Manually, I can do it like this:

```
let myVar : "method1" | "method2" | "method3";
```

But is there any way I can declare this in a dynamic way? So that any of the method I'd add in `obj` would be found as valid value for `myVar`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the `keyof` operator, this will give you a type with all the property names of another type. To get the type of `obj` we use the `typeof` operator.

```
let myVar : keyof typeof obj; // Actual type will be  "method1" | "method2" | "method3"
```

If you add more keys to the object the type of `myVar` will update automatically. But this only works if the keys are known at compile time.

For more about `keyof` see [here](https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2017/01/06/typescript-2-1-keyof-and-lookup-types).